# Question on proving Lebesgue outer measure is countably subadditive

Tags: real-analysis

Outer measure $m^*(A) := $inf{$\sum_{k=1}^\infty$ $l(I_k)$ : $A \subseteq \cup_{k=1}^\infty I_{k}$}

We should prove:

{$E_k$}$_{k=1} ^\infty$ is any countable collection of sets, disjoint or not, then $m^*(\cup_{k=1}^\infty E_k) $ $\le$ $\sum_{k=1}^\infty$ $m^*(E_k)$.

In the progress of proving outer measure is countably subadditive,

Let $\epsilon$ $\gt 0$. For each natural number $k$, there is a countable collection {$I_{k,i}$}$_{i=1} ^\infty$ of open, bounded intervals for which

$E_k$ $\subseteq \cup_{i=1}^\infty I_{k,i}$  and $m^*(E_k)  \le$ $\sum_{i=1}^\infty l(I_{k,i})$ $\lt$ $m^*(E_k)$ $+$ $\frac{\epsilon}{2^k}$ .

I'm confused about the inequality $\sum_{i=1}^\infty l(I_{k,i})$ $\lt$ $m^*(E_k)$ $+$ $\frac{\epsilon}{2^k}$ .

I feel like I can't determine this inequality, because $m^*(E_k)  \le$ $\sum_{i=1}^\infty l(I_{k,i})$

so it seems $\frac{\epsilon}{2^k}$ means nothing, because for any $\epsilon$ $\gt 0$. So, $\epsilon$ may have a really small value.

So how can I determine  $\sum_{i=1}^\infty l(I_{k,i})$ $\lt$ $m^*(E_k)$ $+$ $\frac{\epsilon}{2^k}$ ? How can I understand this inequality??

I'm really confused now...

Comment: What are the $E_k$?

Comment: @kobe oh, I didnt wrote it sorry I will edit it immediately

Comment: This inequality is just the basic property of $\inf$. You see, $m^*(E_k)$ is defined as an infimum: this means that you can choose $\sum_i l(I_{k,i})$ not much larger than $m^*(E_k)$, i.e. $\sum_i l(I_{k,i}) -  m^*(E_k)< \varepsilon / 2^k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $\epsilon > 0$ and positive integer $k$, $m^*(E_k) + \frac{\epsilon}{2^k}$ is not a lower bound of the set of sums $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty l(I_{k,i})$ such that $E_k \subseteq \cup_{i = 1}^\infty I_{k,i}$. That's why you can such choose a covering $\{I_{k,i}\}_{i = 1}^\infty$ for which $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty l(I_{k,i}) < m^*(E_k) + \frac{\epsilon}{2^k}$.

Comment: oh.... I see.... I thought that 'extremely small' means nothing.....(not mathematical, I mean.) I now know how it works.... lower bound.... really thanks.